# Casperjs this.wait() multiple times causes freeze on remote server

Tags: ajax, ubuntu, ssh, casperjs

I'm writing a casperjs script that will scroll to the bottom of the page to load more results through ajax. I'm very familiar with casperjs and my code works fine on my local machine(ubuntu) but when I run it on a remote ubuntu server via ssh terminal, it will hang on any wait after the first this.wait. As you can image, this makes it very hard to complete this kind of ajax functionality.

As an example.

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(1000);
    this.scrollToBottom();
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(1000);
    this.scrollToBottom();
});
```

I notice on my local machine the second wait produces this error in verbose mosde

> [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200): http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=landscapes&qs=ds&form=QBLH&scope=images

This will not display on the remote server since it freezes just before this. By freeze I mean it doesn't move forward, the terminal is still responsive and I can cancel the program and rerun it. It seems as if on the remote server it doesn't know how to handle errors, Even though the code is the same.

Any Help?
Thanks

Comment: I know this might sound stupid... do you have the same version of both CasperJS and PhantomJS on your dev environment and on the server?

Comment: Btw, Writing `this.wait(1000); this.scrollToBottom();` is misleading, because it will be executed the other way around `this.scrollToBottom(); this.wait(1000);`. `wait` is asynchronous, but `scrollToBottom` is not.

Comment: Yes, version of phantom and casper are the same. Both machines are running Ubuntu. Thank you for the tip on the sequence, I think I knew that but it's not the main problem anyway. I've rewritten it many different ways and the second wait always stops it.

Comment: What version of PhantomJS do you use? Maybe you need something like `--web-security=false`, `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` or `--ssl-protocol=any` (or any combination thereof).

Comment: @ElliotRobert If you wish to address a specific person, use the [`@` syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Otherwise they won't get a notification when there are more than one other people in the comment thread.

Comment: @Artjom Yes, those extra commands did the trick. Thank you for those.

Comment: What was the minimal combination of those and what version of PhantomJS do you use?